# Installed TWRP, but still getting Odin?

Tags: cyanogenmod, samsung-galaxy-s-3, twrp, odin

So I'm trying to install CM13 on a Samsung Galaxy S3 (I9300) and I'm following the guide here:

https://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/Install_CM_for_i9300

I've managed to do the first part "Installing a custom recovery", but am thinking that something has gone wrong.

I managed to do all the steps without any hiccups, but in step 11. where

```
11. The Galaxy S III (International) now has a custom recovery installed.
```

I'm not sure whether this really is the case, since when I hold Home + Volume Down + Power to get to recover mode, what I get to is still Odin, eventhough I'd expect this to boot into TWRP. Odin lists the following

```
ODIN MODE
PRODUCT NAME: GT-I9300
CUSTOM BINARY DOWNLOAD: YES (1 counts)
CURRENT BINARY: Samsung Official
SYSTEM STATUS: Official
```

Judging by CUSTOM BINARY DOWNLOAD, something has been downloaded, but did something go wrong in its installation?

What should I do?

Comment: `Home+Volume Down+Power` is **not** the recovery, but the bootloader. The recovery is reached by pressing `Home+Volume UP+Power`. TWRP is a recovery, ODIN is a tool to flash Samsung devices.

Comment: @GiantTree Okay, but doing Home+Volume Up+Power does boot into the "normal" Android system recovery <3e> with the recovery starting with "No command" (which I'm not sure if it's supposed to start like this), but then getting in to the system recovery menu. Where's TWRP?

Comment: Well, apparently you haven't installed TWRP correctly. Make sure it's written correctly to your device. I guess you used Odin to install TWRP. Make sure you've got the latest version of TWRP from https://dl.twrp.me/i9300/.

Comment: @GiantTree Can I revert back to where I started in part 1 of the above guide? I.e. have CUSTOM BINARY DOWNLOAD: YES (1 counts) not showing and not have any partial stuff lying around.

Comment: AFAIK undoing the Download count is not trivial (Triangle Away may be able to do it) but just starting again is safe as you will be just overwriting the stuff you already did.

Comment: @GiantTree Any idea whether I could switch the installation method to use TWRP Manager which I just found, rather than doing the part 1 of the above again? I just want to avoid some kind of unnecessary files or partial installations  being left to my system.

Comment: If your device is already rooted, TWRP Manager should work for you.

Comment: @GiantTree Triangle Away Kinda works. It's like a drunk man fighting (lol)

Comment: @mavavilj Can your device boot normally??

Comment: @DanBrown I've since done a factory reset using Kies and now my phone is back to factory settings and data. I've had troubles getting my phone rooted in order to use TWRP Manager.

Comment: @mavavilj Are you rooted then? If so, just use TWRP manager. If not, follow Giant tree's advice